# How is the number 0.01 spoken in Japanese?

Tags: readings, numbers

How is the number 0.01 correctly spoken in Japanese?
I always thought it is ゼロてんゼロいち, but Google Translate and DeepL give different readings:
ゼロポイントゼロワン and ゼロ点ゼロ1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most common is れい てん れいいち (At least I would read so). れい would be pronounced more like れー.

Other possibilities may be (1)ゼロ てん ゼロいち or (2)れい てん ゼロいち. To me, 1 sounds a little odd, but 2 sounds less so.